# Converting XML single elements to XML attributes using XSLT and keeping as elements in output

Tags: xml, xslt

We have a current system that outputs an XML file which is in the following format:

```
<ResultSet rowCount="2">
    <Row>
     <Entry>83708</Entry>
     <mark>L24653338N1</mark>
     <Processed>NO</Processed>
    </Row>
    <Row>
     <Entry>99999</Entry>
     <mark>L24653338N1</mark>
     <Processed>YES</Processed>
    </Row>
</ResultSet>
```

I need to transform into:

```
<ResultSet rowCount="2">
    <Row Processed="NO">
     <Entry>83708</Entry>
     <mark>L24653338N1</mark>
     <Processed>NO</Processed>
    </Row>
    <Row Processed="YES">
     <Entry>99999</Entry>
     <mark>L24653338N1</mark>
     <Processed>YES</Processed>
    </Row>
</ResultSet>
```

Does someone know how this can be done using .XSL?

Here is what I have done:

```
</xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="transform">
        <Row>
        <xsl:if test="$linecount&gt;0">
            <xsl:for-each       select="/Msg/Body/Payload[./@Role='S']/Msg/Body/Payload[./@sql]/SqlResult/ResultSet/Row">
                <xsl:attribute name="pos"><xsl:value-of select="position()"/></xsl:attribute>
                <Entry>
                    <xsl:value-of select="./Entry"/>
                </Entry>
                <mark>
                    <xsl:value-of select="./mark"/>
                </mark>
                <Proccessed>
                    <xsl:value-of select="./Proccessed"/>
                </Proccessed>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:if>
    </Row>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: "*Does someone know how this can be done using .XSL?*" Yes, there are plenty of folks here who know how to *that* (hint: it's an XSLT beginner's task) . Are you looking for help in doing this yourself - or do you just expect someone to do your work for you?

Comment: On *SO*, the community expects that people show research effort before asking a question. So please at least show us what you've tried.

Comment: Here is what I have done just not sure how to take the element and place it as an attribute of Row. I know it is a beginner's task. I am new to xsl so please excuse the simple question. I have seen examples that will convert all elements into the attribute but cant seem to get it to work.

Comment: I'd suggest you start with an [identity transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform#Using_XSLT) template. Then add a template matching `Row` and make it add a `Processed` attribute to the `Row` and apply templates to its children.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In tasks such as these, where you are only making changing to part of the XML, the usual approach is to start with the [Identity Transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform)

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

On its own it will copy all the nodes and attributes as-is, so you only need to write templates for the things you wish to change. In your case you are adding a new `Processed` attribute onto the `Row` element. This means you only need a template that matches the `Row` element that then adds this attribute, like so

```
<xsl:template match="Row">
    <Row Processed="{Processed}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </Row>
</xsl:template>
```

Notice the use of [Attribute Value Templates](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#attribute-value-templates) in the attribute you are creating. The curly braces `{}` indicate an expression to be evalualted, not output literally, and so the value of the attribute will actually be the value of the `Processed` element.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="Row">
        <Row Processed="{Processed}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </Row>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that you call also create attributes with [xsl:attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#creating-attributes). For example

```
<xsl:template match="Row">
    <Row>
        <xsl:attribute name="Processed">
            <xsl:value-of select="Processed" />
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </Row>
</xsl:template>
```

But as you can see, this is more verbose, so Attribute Value Templates are preferred where possible.